# Revolution Slider did not start transition automatically until i click on that dot button of slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have installed revolution slider and it's loading perfectly on my home page. But the pre-loader of revolution slider does not start the transition. When I click on the small dot of slider number then it appears and starts the transition. Why doesn't it start automatically when my homepage loads?.

Comment: You need to show some code, if you want people to help you.

Comment: Improved English